# How to remove lowest elements in list?

Tags: python, list

Given my List:

```
arr=[['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]
```

I have to remove elements containing lowest numbers

i.e elements:

```
['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
arr=[['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
min_value=min(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])
min_marks=min_value[1]
for i in arr:
    if i[1]==min_marks:
        arr.remove(i)
```

but this is not giving the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: [Thou Shalt Not Modify A List During Iteration](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/)

Summary: When we remove the first element containing 19, the rest "slide down". For example, when we removed `arr[2]` aka `['Varun', 19]`, `['Kakunami', 19]` replaced it. Then, the loop continued to `arr[3]` which is now `['Vikas', 21]`. This, in a way, left `['Kakunami', 19]` out of the loop.

Solution: To work around this, just loop over the list from the reverse order: (Have to use a `while`...I think)

```
arr=[['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]

arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
min_value=min(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])
min_marks=min_value[1]

i = len(arr) - 1;
while i >= 0:
  if arr[i][1]==min_marks:
    arr.remove(arr[i])
  i = i - 1

print arr
```

[A repl.it as a demo](https://repl.it/@chrishappy/FrozenNativeMisrac)

You could do this recursively:

```
arr=[['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]

arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
min_value=min(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])
min_marks=min_value[1]

def removeLowest(arr, min):
  for i in arr:
      if i[1]==min_marks:
          arr.remove(i)
          return removeLowest(arr, min)
  return arr

removeLowest(arr, min)

print arr
```

Otherwise, there are many other alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a new list then this will work:

```
arr = [['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]
min_number = min(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
arr = [pair for pair in arr if pair[1] != min_number]
```

Otherwise you may want to look at some of the answers here: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying your code too much, this is possible to achieve using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

```py
arr = [['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
min_value = min(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])
min_marks = min_value[1]

arr = [ elem for elem in arr if elem[1] != min_marks]
```

It's not good to remove elements from a list like this whilst you're iterating over it. Instead, you may want to form a list of indicies to remove and use the `.remove()` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution I could think of:

```
arr=[['Harsh', 20], ['Beria', 20], ['Varun', 19], ['Kakunami', 19], ['Vikas', 21]]

lowest = sorted(set([i[1] for i in arr]))[0]

output = [i for i in arr if i[1] != lowest]
```

It simply checks for the lowest value in arr, and removes the list containing lowest value from final output